# Scale and Translate Image Android Issue

Tags: android, android-animation

I am trying to implement a translate and scale animation together using AnimationSet.

This is what i am trying to acheive

[image]

**img1,2,3 are images which i want to scale (original size to small) and translate it all to one position of the screen .**

**img4 is a big image which fadesIn in its own position , in all img1,2,3 scale,translate to new position and img4 fades in and shows up in that position**

**My xml Layout**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="80" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview1"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:src="@drawable/wedding_normal" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview2"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:src="@drawable/wedding_normal" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview3"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:src="@drawable/wedding_normal" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="20" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Code i am using**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ImageView iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
        final int amountToMoveRight = 200;
        final int amountToMoveDown = 700;

        AnimationSet animSet = new AnimationSet(true);
        animSet.setFillAfter(true);
        animSet.setDuration(5000);

        TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, amountToMoveRight,
                0, amountToMoveDown);

        anim.setFillAfter(true);
        animSet.addAnimation(anim);
        ScaleAnimation scale = new ScaleAnimation(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.5f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float) 1,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float) 0.5);

        scale.setFillAfter(true);
        animSet.addAnimation(scale);
        iv1.startAnimation(animSet);        
    }

}
```

**I am able to translate somewhat properly , but i am not able to get the scale animation right**

Comment: what are the symptoms?

Comment: the 'symptoms' are it translates and scales but as it scales it doesnt go to the actual position where it was to translate to

Comment: first add ScaleAnimation then TranslateAnimation